# Cocoa: how to prevent mouse move past coordinates?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Final goal is to prevent mouse move to another screen (dual display setup) unless a hotkey is held.

The best I came up with, is this:

```
[NSEvent addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:NSMouseMovedMask handler:^(NSEvent *mouseMovedEvent) {
   // does nothing yet
}]
```

The reason I went for global monitor is that my app does not have any windows (and views), it's a status bar app. So `NSTrackingArea` went home.

Any help would be much appreciated. In Java world, I would simply `preventDefault()` the event object. Now I need to get the same functionality in Objective-C. Ideally, I'd wish there would be "MouseMovedPastScreen" event, but apparently there's not.

Thanks.

---

#### EDIT

Again, in Java, I would get the bounds of both screens, and stopped mouse at the corner positions. And then would allow the event to bubble if the `⌘` key has been held during the event execution.

Comment: What's the specific issue that you're stuck on _right now_? How to get the mouse's location? How to get the screen size? Complaining about how easy your task is in another framework doesn't help anyone help you solve your problem.

Comment: Yes, I've been reading about different classes since the question posted. Basically now I'm stuck at preventing the mouse move itself, i.e objective-c version of java's `preventDefault()`. Now I know how to get screen(s) frame(s), `mouseLocation` etc.

Comment: A global event monitor isn't allowed to change the events that are passed in to it, only observe them. I think a [`CGEventTap`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/QuartzEventServicesRef/Reference/reference.html) can do it, but I'm not certain.

Answer (score 2):

[Controlling the mouse cursor](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/QuartzDisplayServicesConceptual/Articles/MouseCursor.html) From the Quartz Display Services programming guide. Particularly

```
CGAssociateMouseAndMouseCursorPosition (false);
```

Comment: Yeah, but the docs say `To use these functions, your application must be in the foreground.` while I have a status bar app.